# what does cross sign means in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project opened in eclipse, its a java web application. In eclipse I can see that there is a red cross sign with my project name, On expanding my project I can see many files have the same red cross sign.

What does this cross sign means in eclipse? Is it showing some compilation error? if error how can I see the error? Also what does that triangle icon means?

[image]

Please check the screenshot above and see the `cross and triangle` signs...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cross on red ground means an error in this file, while a question mark on yellow ground indicates a warning. You can see them in the **Problems tab** in eclipse:

[image: Eclipse problems tab]

You can customize what is treated as an error and as a warning under `Window -> Preferences` and then search for `errors/warnings` (Also take a look at the docs: [Java Compiler Errors/Warnings Preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm)

In addition to the markings on the resources, you can see errors and warnings in an open file next to the scroll bar:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Cross sign shows the error in that Source,Triangle indicates that your source has some warinings

Just open those files could find the Red `x` under line and marks in the source editor , if warnings will be displayed as Triangle with `!` in the side bar of the source editor

If your source code is large then you can use shortcut `ctrl + .` to see the errors in the source file. The following shortcuts will move to the warnings and errors from top to bottom in your eclipse

Few shortcuts to see the errors in eclipse:

```
Next error: `Ctrl + .`
Previous error: `Ctrl + ,`
Quick fixes: `Ctrl + 1`
```

Answer (score 2):

The cross sign indicates that the file web.xml has some error. Also, possibly some files within the 'jsp' and 'lib' directories also have error.

The yellow triangles are warnings. To see the details of all, Go to `Window -> Show view -> Problems`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anyone mentioning one thing that may be confusing to a beginner: the red X appears on the file with the error **as well as** on all its parents. These other marks are a great convenience when your tree is collapsed—they lead you to the file in error, but can also cause confusion when viewing an expanded tree.

Every error marked with the red X annotation also appears in the Problems view, **if the view's filter is properly configured**. You configure the filter through the view's local menu (accessed through the little downward-facing triangle in the top-right corner of the view's title bar).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means you have an error, whereas the yellow triangle with the exclamation mark means you have a warning.
You can view the error by opening the file. The line with the error will an error mark on the left margin.

Answer (score 1):

It means your projects contains **error**, if appears red-cross.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your project contains error,if it shows red-cross

General way you can see `Window > Show View > Problems`

The easy way using shut cut key `Alt+Shift+Q,X`